# Crystal Report and LineChart

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm building a report with Crystal Report with Visual Studio 2015.
Now in my report I want to add a Line Chart. 
The table that populate my chart is like this:

CREATE TABLE #T_TEMPERATURA (
        NOME NVARCHAR(100),
        ORA DATETIME,
        VALORE DECIMAL(5,2)
    )

This is the result set of this query:

```
    NOME                    ORA                     VALORE
    TEMPERATURA RILEVATA    2018-01-12 08:00:00.000 40  
    TEMPERATURA RILEVATA    2018-01-12 16:00:00.000 37  
    TEMPERATURA RILEVATA    2018-01-12 18:00:00.000 39  
    TEMPERATURA RILEVATA    2018-01-12 20:00:00.000 41  
    TEMPERATURA STANDARD    2018-01-12 08:00:00.000 37  
    TEMPERATURA STANDARD    2018-01-12 16:00:00.000 37  
    TEMPERATURA STANDARD    2018-01-12 18:00:00.000 37  
    TEMPERATURA STANDARD    2018-01-12 20:00:00.000 37
```

So, when I try yo set Chart Expert I have this situation:

[image]

But if I try to start my report I have this wrong LineChart:

[image]

As Legend I should to have "Temperatura Standard" and " Temperatura Rilevata".

How can I change it ?

Comment: are you using 2 tables in report?

Comment: No I use one table that have that result ? As you can see Table21